# Как избавится от switch php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно рефакторить этот код чтоб обойтись без **switch**

```
public function getCodDoc($kod_doc)
{
    switch ($kod_doc) {
        case "retail":
            $kod_doc = $this->retail;
            break;
        case "bn":
            $kod_doc = $this->bn;
            break;
        case "bnfab":
            $kod_doc = $this->bnfab;
            break;
        case "ya":
            $kod_doc = $this->ya;
            break;
        case "ret":
            $kod_doc = $this->ret;
            break;
    }

    return $kod_doc;
}
```

Comment: return $this->{$kod_doc}

Comment: Используйте [match](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.match.php) =) Если пока не можете, оставьте как есть, незачем рефакторить вполне понятный код. Ну или заведите массив с отображением.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, это не эквивалентный код, нужен белый список или хотя бы property_exists.

Comment: @vp_arth все зависит от ситуации.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я бы действительно добавил кейс по умолчанию, return `$this->{$kod_doc} ?? $kod_doc;`

Comment: @Ипатьев тогда уж либо `null` либо `throw`

Comment: @teran с точки зрения здравого смысла - да, с точки зрения того кода который написан в вопросе - это его точная копия.